# Manipulate data after Contact form 7 is submited

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have contact form 7, form in my Wordpress site.
I want when form is submitted (and mail has sent) to pass via post method, the data to onother PHP file. In my last PHP file I have code to send form's data to a CRM system.

I have searched over the internet for a solution. Some people say its easy some other not. But at the end there isn't any example on how to do that.
Also I did not found anything in CF7 documentation.

What I found is hook and actions.

The only logical solution I found is that in this [link](http://jamesleist.com/capture-data-on-form-submit-in-contact-form-7/) .

But I don't understand where to put the code and how to call it.

Comment: put that code in functions.php of your theme or a custom plugin.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to create a custom Plugin. Then you can add the code listed in your link to your Plugin code.

A guide to Plugin development can be found [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin). A good Plugin template to get you started can be downloaded from [here](https://github.com/mattyza/starter-plugin).